# Wrong catch default value into textbox with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have problem load default data into textbox on controller, but when i use i submit form validate. It still catch the same value in textbox that we load default data. When false validation i dont want to show default value again.

How to solve?

Code in controller

$data['defaultvalue'] ='Hello'

```
   if($this->input->post('btntransfer')!=""){
   if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){  

    }else{

    }
```

COde in View:

```
<form method="post">
<input type="text"  id="txt1" name="txt1" value="<?php echo $defaultvalue?$defaultvalue:''; ?>"/>
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Transfer" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST[txt1])
{
    $defaultvalue=$_POST[txt1];
}
else
{
    $defaultvalue='';
}
?>

<input type="text"  id="txt1" name="txt1" value="<?php echo $defaultvalue; ?>"/>
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Transfer" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you want to pass the different $defaultvalue right back to your form if the validation fails:

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {

     $data['defaultvalue'] = $this->input->post('txt1', TRUE);

} else {
 //something
}
```